# Is it possible to tell if there are any ongoing 'GET' requests with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to tell if there are any ongoing 'GET' requests with javascript?

I have a feeling that it is not. Basically I don't want to make a seperate request while the other "more important" requests are going as this one is fairly heavy. So I was curious if it is possible to tell if there are currently 'get' requests going and if so I can tell my function to hold off for this update and do it again in 10-15secs.

Any information etc would be appreciated.

Comment: The call I am making is. The ones I want to wait for are simply image requests. URL stays the same image at said URL updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this using just javascript. You can use a framework like jQuery and manage all the requests using a plugin like [ajax manager](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/).

Comment: Not what I was thinking of per se. But I can use to suit my needs perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: jQuery is written in JavaScript; anything that can be done in jQuery can also be done in plain JavaScript.

Comment: @casablanca you are correct but I tagged the question with jQuery as my project is already using it.

Comment: @Thqr: My comment was meant for @Teja Kantamneni, as he mentioned "I don't think you can do this using just javascript."

Comment: @casablanca - Yes, I accept it. What I actually mean is you have to have a wrapper kind of thing for all the requests you do and in the process we may need to reinvent most of the stuff which is already available in many javascript frameworks. I picked jQuery as only an example

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any built in api for it, but it's as simple as setting a global flag for it.

```
var get = 0;

function somethingeasy() {
  get++;
  $.get(somethingeasy, function() {
    get--;
    stuff;
  });
};

function somethinghard() {
  if(get)
  {
     setTimeout('somethinghard',1000);
     return false;
  }
  get++;
  $.get(somethinghard, function() {
    get--;
    stuff;
  });
};
```

Comment: I understand and use similiar in other places however I have no control over the requests in this particular part. Hence the looking for some way of controlling what 'get' requests are currently actually running seen as it can get up to about 40. Thanks for the fast response though.

Comment: Personally would change the `get` variable name and treat it as a boolean than relying on "truthy" and "falsy" values, but a pretty good implementation.

Comment: I considered changing the name since it's undeployable as is, but since it's just an illustration I favored readability.  As for the truthy, I used a bool when I first posted it, but it didn't really deal with the multiple small gets issue.

Comment: I agree for readability wise the example is really nice. Also have to always agree on the boolean value as well though. If true is true and true is also equal to true then lets do something :)

Answer (score 1):

If all the AJAX calls are made with jQuery, you can use the [`ajaxSend()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) event...

```
$.ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, settings) {
  if(settings.method == "GET") {
    alert("GET request is being made...");
  }
});
```

Comment: This would work great but sadly the requests I want to wait for are not being made with jQuery,

Comment: @Thqr Depending on the size of your code base, it just may be worth converting.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looking for requests directly, you can use ready/load events to check when they are done - presumably you know which objects you want to wait for. If you want to wait for all images to load, don't let your code run until after document.load has been called.

Comment: Images reload and change systematically. Well after load has been called. I wanted to prevent having the images loading and my KML feed loading at the same time because they get rather caught up on each other.

Comment: You can get load events on individual images also. That is quite easy to convert to a hasloaded check by setting an attribute when the load event is called. Assume anything without hasloaded set is trying to load and you have your check for get requests.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 2+ you can use:

```
  $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    return console.log("an ajax event started");
  });
  $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    return console.log("all ajax events stopped");
  });
```